# Using AJAX and Jquery without a form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have used JQuery with Ajax successfully before, but only for form elements (using GET and POST). I am trying to figure out how to do use Jquery and AJAX for non-form elements. I have a list like this:

- item1
- item2

When the user clicks on an item, I need it to hit the server and write the item number in the database without it refreshing the page.

Can someone pleasehelp me?

---

Edit: Using PHP

Here is the code I am working with but don't know how to use properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rating_toggle").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rating/test",
        data: "????????",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Post the page markup please.

Comment: You have to use the $.ajax() method, but really it's hard to help you without knowing what server language you are using.

Comment: the data you send depends on how the server side language expects it.  jquery will serialize an object for you when you use ajax, so just create an object for data, get the values you want from your markup, and proceed as usual.

Comment: it's all going to be in POST, just like a form would be.  It's all just key/value pairs sent via a query string URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still send in a ajax request clicking elements which are non form elements..

Remove the return false from your Request .. That is not required..

```
$('li').on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
            url : 'rating/test',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : { your data},
            success :  function(result){
                alert('Inserted into database')
             },
             error : function(xhr,text ,error){
                alert('Error occured !!')
             }
           });

});
```

Comment: What does beside "data"? And how do I call the data within the PHp file?

Comment: You can use $_POST["variable"] to get the data of that particular variable

Comment: Sorry - what goes beside data? Do I throw the ID of the list item?

Comment: It depends on what you want to send.. If you just want to send in the id of the item you can do that or extra parameters .. data : { 'id' :   this.id , 'param2' : 'param2'}

Comment: So for data, this is what I am passing: data : { 'item' : selectListItem} and in the php, I am doing echo $_POST['item']; but the data isnt being passed back into the javascript alert

Comment: access it on php using $_POST["item"]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19901/discussion-between-steeped-and-sushanth)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it...

- use `$(selector).on('click', function(){ ... })` to bind an event to be triggered by clicking your list items
- use `$(this).index()` to get the index of the item in relation to it's siblings (from within the bound click function)
- use `$.post(url,data,success_callback)` to send the data to the server, where `url` is a simple url string, data is a javascript object built from the data you want to send, and `success_callback` is a function run after the server side sends confirmation of receipt/processing.

On the server, php will receive a request, with a bunch of `$_POST` data, which matches up to the keys of the data object sent in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this quick little snippet

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').click(function() {
        var selectListItem = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "yourserverpage.php",
            data: { selectedItem: selectListItem },
            success: function(returnData) { alert('Saved '+selectListItem+' and returned '+ returnData); }
        });
    });
});
```